# How to call link TextView from other Layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm using TextView as a link in Main Activity, When I click this link it happened an error
This is my activity: (***UPDATED***)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_activity, null, false);
    TextView text = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.mapTextView);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

my second_activity.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mapTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Test Link"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
...
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            View viewONE = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.first_activity, parent, false);
            CustomViewHolder rowONE = new CustomViewHolder(viewONE);
            return rowONE;

        case 2:
            View viewTWO = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.second_activity, parent, false);
            CustomViewHolder rowTWO = new CustomViewHolder(viewTWO);
            return rowTWO;
 }
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.totoroads.android.app, PID: 5699
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.totoroads.android.app/com.totoroads.android.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.totoroads.android.app.MainActivity .onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
```

varialbe ***mapTextView*** I don't set in main_activity.xml and set in other(second_activity.xml)

How to call mapTextView in other layout ? thank you !

Answer (score 0):

when you dont set it stores null hence you need to initialize it
try this first `mapTextView = findViewById(R.id.mapTextView);`
An example main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void sendMessage(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

Now second activity you want to switch

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       TextView textView = new TextView(this);
       textView.setTextSize(40);
       textView.setText(message);

       ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
       layout.addView(textView);
    }
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but my second_acitvity.xml is inflated by ViewGroup from an Adapter

Comment: I have posted adapter class more

Comment: try this first `mapTextView = findViewById(R.id.mapTextView);`ignore other things for moment.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call a view doesn't existed on the screen !!

but, if your SecondActivity is running. you can connected to the TextView using interfaces or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) Library.

Comment: Thank for your advice, It still exist on the screen because it's CardView Layout in Adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

As you have done above in your MainActivity, now you can only get reference of all those objects that are in activity_main.

Now in order to achieve your desired functionality, (get the reference of textview which is in **second_activity.xml**), you have to inflate second_activity.xml using **layout Inflator** then you can perform and handle **OnClick** task in MainActivity.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_activity.xml, null, false);
TextView text = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.mapTextView);
text.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You can also include **second_activity.xml** in your **activity_main.xml** to achieve your functionality.

Comment: I have updated Activity above, it's not apprear error, but Textview can not link to other activity

Comment: Have you debug your app?? What's the error in this case ??

Comment: As you see, I want to get TextView from second_activity.xml and display as a link, and then click this link, it will link to other activity

Comment: I'm not debug yet, maybe I have to check again